# Topaz Signature Sigplus web. Is it possible to set windowless in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins, npapi

I have been trying to find a way to set sigplus web for Firefox into a windowless mode.

I have look in the Vendors website with no luck. Couldnt find anything related to it.
I have also experiment with the different properties found in the sigplus object within the DOM, also with negative results.

There's not much documentation out there on it. Does anyone know if this is possible??? Or if there is a workaround so that the signature container wont show on top of my fixed positioned Divs??

This is for Firefox, so, its more for the NPAPI version of it, not the activeX.

This is the website of the npapi version: [http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/download/sigplusweb.htm](http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/download/sigplusweb.htmhttp://www.topazsystems.com/Software/download/sigplusweb.htm)

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place to ask such a question, since it would require inside information about a specific plugin.  There is nothing in the npapi spec itself to force one windowing model or another, so unless one of the developers for the plugin you're talking about happens by (and you didn't even link to where it is, I've never heard of it before) you're most likely out of luck.

Comment: I'm pretty much out of options. Perhaps someone has worked with electronic signatures and used this software. Or perhaps theres a known hack with which might help achieve the desire functionality.

Comment: It's actually usually much more difficult to build a windowless plugin than a windowed one; chances are good it's not possible

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor? They would be in the best position tell you if they support it.